# SPAdes installation error: "This header is only meant to be used on x86 and x64 architecture"

Tags: bioinformatics

I am new to using Bioinformatics tools like SPAdes (Bioinformatics tool).

**Machine Used:** Apple M1, Ventura 13.5.1

**What I've tried:** I am trying to install SPAdes following the [GIT page](https://github.com/ablab/spades#sec3.4), with all dependencies. When running the below command, I am getting an error.

```
./spades_compile.sh
```

**Error:**
I received an error like.

```
#error "This header is only meant to be used on x86 and x64 architecture"
```

There were multiple similar errors like this & it stopped automatically.
[image]

**What I've tried:**

1. One of the related [issue in GIT for ARCH linux types](https://github.com/ablab/spades/issues/340) - had a statement "pre-built binaries might not be universally usable due to variety of distributions with unique restrictions, etc."
2. Went through [SPAdes manual](https://cab.spbu.ru/files/release3.13.1/manual.html#sec3.2) unable to get related info.

Please let me know if I can use this in my MAC OS Ventura M1 or any alternate solution.

Comment: Have you already tried to download the pre-compiled binaries for Mac?

Comment: As per the git doc, it dowloads & compiles. I am not aware of precompiled version for SPAdes, suggest one if you knew already. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a Mac user, but I thought that this section of the git doc would provide the binaries for Mac ("Darwin"): https://github.com/ablab/spades#sec2.2 I don't know if these are working for ARM-64 processors but that's why I was asking if you tried that already